# cannot access ubuntu after restart chromebook

Tags: bash, chromebook, chroot

I downloaded Ubuntu on my Samsung Chromebook 2, and I really enjoy it! I shut down my Chromebook, and I tried the command <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Forward</kbd> like I did before I shut it off, and It did not work. I searched it up and saw that I may have to go into the Chrome OS terminal and type in "shell" enter `sudo startunity` And I did make sure that my Chromebook was in dev mode before all of that ^

I then got this message under that command :

```
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...

_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.10.18 #1 SMP Fri Dec 11 19:18:20 PST 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=a687a3ef-7b3c-d643-884f-9c8c71b902d3/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=a687a3ef-7b3c-d643-884f-9c8c71b902d3/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=9dc5e01612a9a39940b3e401eea76252d377c8ae salt=882a85e22f6795821598d31581f0be109557c552116a01b48a0be86871733bfc" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=a687a3ef-7b3c-d643-884f-9c8c71b902d3 add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic  
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:01PM
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.17 (For technical support please see ubuntudotcom ) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
        Before reporting problems, check wikidotxdotorg
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log", Time: Tue Dec 29 19:29:55 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for additional information.

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
```

I downloaded Ubuntu last week and got this message, And I couldn't find anything on it. During the week I was thinking that It was me who did something, but after i did it again this time, I don't think it was me anymore. Also, in the message that was sent after the command, ubuntuedotcom and the wiki one were the actual websites, but this is my first question on this site, and I could not have more than 1 link so I had to spell it out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Crouton is just another boot-loader, so once Crouton got Ubuntu up-and-running, it's just plain old Ubuntu (without grub). **However, questions *about the Crouton boot-process itself* are off-topic...)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use xiwi. Xiwi should get Crouton working for you as it routes the X11 server into a window for you. See: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/crouton-in-a-Chromium-OS-window-%28xiwi%29

However, if you're not interested in that fix then I'll elaborate your problem and try to help. What you've stumbled on to a known bug that can be fixed by downgrading ChromeOS (I don't recommend this) and perhaps trying a different version of Ubuntu. Which reminds me it would be nice to know your exact versions that you're working with here.  Okay so if you wanna keep trying to get this work try this:

```
> shell
$ sudo enter-chroot
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
$ ls -l /dev/dri
crw-rw---- 1 root video 226, 0 Dec 27 13:18 card0
crw-rw---- 1 root video 226, 1 Dec 27 13:18 card1
[...truncated...]
$ sudo rm /dev/dri/card0
$ sudo mv /dev/dri/card1 /dev/dri/card0
```

If you don't see card1 and card0 don't bother with the above commands.The above may get it to work for you but you may run in to problems where you have to re-run these command after every reboot.

A little more detail on your specific issue can be found here: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/1978

Comment: Thanks snorp for the comment! I just tried the enter chroot, and nothing with "card" showed up. What it did do was put the word "precise" in front of my username. I then tried to put in sudo startunity, and is asked for my password, which I put in, and then it had the message "Do not launch gnome-session-wrapper as root inside the chroot." sorry it didnt let me edit my last comment

Comment: What did show up? Also what version of Chrome are you using? If I understood correctly this was working and then suddenly stopped? Were any updates applied?

Comment: i got it working.... got the xiwi and all the good stuff, i can use ubuntu in another window now on chrome, and it works great. Thanks alot!!!

Comment: @CamCollyer: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: CamCollyer glad you got it working! @Fabby per your comment above, I know I'm new on askubuntu but for what it's worth I agree that it's off topic too.

Comment: Otherwise you would have received an upvote from me!  **;-)** Now the best you can have is an acceptance and maybe the then the Q&A won't be deleted!  **:/**